# How to add multiple charts into different sheets of one excel?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to export multiple charts I created using xlsxwriter into multiple sheets in one excel. I have two dataframes as below:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','102','103','104','105','106'],'CountA':[7,8,9,10,11,12],'CountB':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'CountC':[13,14,15,16,17,18]})

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'User':['107','108','109','110','111','112'],'ValA':[10,20,30,40,50,60],'ValB':[70,80,90,100,110,120],'ValC':[130,140,150,160,170,180]})
```

I have successfully create one excel file, namely "test.xlsx" which contains df_a and its corresponding stacked bar chart using the code below:

```
#Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
 excel_file_a = 'test.xlsx'
 sheet_name_a = 'testA'

 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_a, engine='xlsxwriter')
 df_a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name_a,index=False)

#Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
 workbook = writer.book
 worksheet_a = writer.sheets[sheet_name_a]

#Create a chart object.
 chart_a = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})

#Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
 for col_num in range(1, 4):
     chart_a.add_series({
         'name':       ['testA', 0, col_num],
         'categories': ['testA', 1, 0, 5, 0],
         'values':     ['testA', 1, col_num, 5, col_num],
         'gap':        2,
                         })

#Insert the chart into the worksheet.
 worksheet_a.insert_chart('G2', chart_a)

#Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
 writer.save()
```

However, I also want df_b and its respective stacked bar chart in the same excel file, "test.xlsx" but in a different sheet, let say sheetname = testB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good place to use a loop.  For example:

```or-tag-here
# You only need one of each of these
excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_a, engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book  
dataframes = (df_a, df_b)

# Loop through our list of dataframes
for i in range(len(dataframes)):
    sheet_name = 'test' + 'abcdefghijklmnop'[i]    # testa, testb, etc.
    dataframe = dataframes[i]

    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
    ....
    # all of the other stuff down as far as...
    worksheet.insert_chart('G2', chart)

# Now that we have finished our loop
writer.save()
```

Comment: Hi, i tested your method and I only get results for df_a.

Comment: ahh nvm, its because the indentation on the last writer.save(). get it now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I've just made a copy and paste of your code and changed a couple of things.
I don't know what was your problem, maybe you were overwriting something.

```
    excel_file_a = 'test.xlsx'
    sheet_name_a = 'testA'
    sheet_name_b = 'testB'

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_a, engine='xlsxwriter')

    df_a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name_a,index=False)
    df_b.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name_b,index=False)

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet_a = writer.sheets[sheet_name_a]
    worksheet_b = writer.sheets[sheet_name_b]

    chart_a= workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})
    chart_b= workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})

    for col_num in range(1, 4):
          chart_a.add_series({
             'name':       ['testA', 0, col_num],
             'categories': ['testA', 1, 0, 5, 0],
             'values':     ['testA', 1, col_num, 5, col_num],
             'gap':        2,
                             })

    for col_num in range(1, 4):
          chart_b.add_series({
             'name':       ['testB', 0, col_num],
             'categories': ['testB', 1, 0, 5, 0],
             'values':     ['testB', 1, col_num, 5, col_num],
             'gap':        2,
                             })

    worksheet_a.insert_chart('G2', chart_a)
    worksheet_b.insert_chart('G3', chart_b)

    writer.save()
```

[image: worksheet b]

[image: worksheet a]

Comment: yeah, initially i tried this way too but i only get for df_a. I think i might be overwriting something. thanks anyway!