# Create charts in multiple sheets using Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I've an excel file(.xlsx) with multiple sheets of data. Is it possible to create and insert charts for each sheets separately. I've been trying with `pandas` and `xlsxwriter` but the xlsxwriter seems to only add chart on a workbook not on a worksheet. Please let me know if there is a way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in one of the other questions. guess that will work.
[Link to the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690222/how-to-add-multiple-charts-into-different-sheets-of-one-excel)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).